# How can I access output of previous Ptransform in next step

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have to create a Apache data beam in Python which has to do following functions-

1. Read an entry from a database table matching a particular criteria
2. Call 1st REST API for this record
3. In the response of above API call, will get an array. Call two API for each element in this array
4. Update the data fetched by all 3 API calls in DB

One thing I could not find on web was how can I pass the output of any step(Ptransform) to next one. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The example bellow demonstrate the process of pass the output of one processing step (PTransform) to the next.

```py
import apache_beam as beam

class ReadFromDatabase(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        # Simulating reading data from the database
        return pcoll | 'ReadFromDatabase' >> beam.Create([{'id': 1, 'name': 'example'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'another_example'}])

class CallFirstAPI(beam.PTransform):
    class ProcessElement(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element):
            # Using a method to access and transform database data
            transformed_data = {'id': element['id'], 'name': element['name'], 'api_data': 'api_response'}
            print(f"CallFirstAPI - Processed Element: {transformed_data}")
            yield transformed_data

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return pcoll | 'CallFirstAPI' >> beam.ParDo(self.ProcessElement())

class CallSecondAPI(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        # Simulating calling the second API and transforming the data
        return pcoll | 'CallSecondAPI' >> beam.Map(lambda x: {'id': x['id'], 'name': x['name'], 'api_data': x['api_data'], 'additional_data': 'more_info'})

pipeline = beam.Pipeline()
read_from_db = pipeline | 'ReadFromDatabase' >> ReadFromDatabase()
call_first_api = read_from_db | 'CallFirstAPI' >> CallFirstAPI()
call_second_api = call_first_api | 'CallSecondAPI' >> CallSecondAPI()

result = pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

Additional Points:

1. The Apache Beam Programming Guide may lack sufficient Python examples (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#applying-transforms) :/
2. If the data from API calls doesn't change frequently, consider using side-inputs to optimize the pipeline. Check the documentation on side-inputs for more details: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/.
3. If external API data changes frequently, another recommended approach is to group calls to external services efficiently. Refer to the documentation on grouping elements for efficient external service calls:
   https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/grouping-elements-for-efficient-external-service-calls/

Comment: Thanks @Raefael. I have couple of questions about the asnwer-
1)In 'expand' in 'CallFirstAPI', I did not understand how I can access the data read from 
    DB.Will it be using variable pcoll?
2)I need these operations to happen on all the rows in DB table. So, my query in step 1 should fetch only 1 record and not all, is it correct?

Comment: Hi @SumitDesai, I updated the answer including how to access the elements.
You probably gonna use an [IO Connector](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/) for reading the database. For example, using [JdbcIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html#apache_beam.io.jdbc.ReadFromJdbc) you will configure the connection, query, fetch_size and many others parameters to read from a DB.